# Cannot create partition in Disk Utility

Tags: disk-utility, partition

So I'm trying to restore Mavericks on an iMAC.

Internet Recovery loads fine but "Install OSX" shows no disk to select, so I run "Disk Utility".

It shows me "Untitled" drive which is a 3TB HDD (and the startup disk of course). It is "Online" and "Repair" says it's working fine. I select it but all options and buttons are disabled. I can't do anything.

I can't attach any screenshot because I'm in the middle of Internet Recovery.

Please assist.

Comment: Precisely which Mac model? What OS was last on it?

Comment: I think it's a 2012 or 2013 iMac. Previously Windows 10 was installed directly without bootcamp. So I erased all partitions on the disk and now it is "Untitled" and I can't do anything.

Comment: Try another erase. In Disk Utility, press Cmd/2 so you can see devices as well as volumes. Erase the entire drive. GUID/HFS Extended.

Comment: I don't have a Mac keyboard so I tried Windows+2 and nothing changed. Perhaps it's because there's no "View" item in Disk Utility menu?

Comment: Oh, sorry, back in Mavericks was before they hid the devices by default. You should be able to see the actual disk not just partitioning. Try a full erase as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue:

1. Open `Terminal` from `Utilities` menu.
2. Run `diskutil list` to find the disk ID. In my case it was `/dev/disk0`
3. The command to erase a disk and create a new partition is: `diskutil eraseDisk FILE_SYSTEM DISK_NAME DISK_IDENTIFIER` so for me it was `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Empty /dev/disk0`

Now OS X Installer sees my drive.